# Errors in Schematic made in Altium Designer

Tags: altium, ground, error, schematic, netlists

I am using Altium Designer as ECAD tool for first time to create the schematics. There are few errors which are popping up and I don't know how to get rid of those errors.
First one is regarding HI and LI pin of half bridge MOSFET gate driver I am using and these two pins are connected with Micro-controller so for this functional block I configured these two pin as an input. Since I have to do small filtering of this PWM coming from Micro-controller, so as soon as I add a resistor to this pin, there is an error"[Error]Net NetR816_1 has only one pin (Pin R816-1)" attached screenshot below:
[image]

Second one is error coming from OPamp. The pin4 which is ground pin when I connect this to power ground which is HV_GND in this case there is an Error"[Error]HV_GND contains Power Pin and Input Port objects (Pin U301-4, Pin U302-4, Port Sense_V-)"attached screenshot below:
[image]

Can anyone please let me know how to debug these errors.
Thanks

Comment: This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

Answer (score 1):

> as soon as I add a resistor to this pin, there is an error"[Error]Net NetR816_1 has only one pin (Pin R816-1)" attached screenshot below:

R816 is connected to a port with a name of `PWM_U_Phase_HS`. This node appears to be floating because if there's no other port with the same name in the <s>circuit</s> project then you'll get this error. If you put an output port to, say, an MCU's pin and give the same name then the compiler will know that the resistor connects to the MCU's pin. Note that the port should be in a schematic of the same project.

---

I can't say a thing about the second order, sorry. I'd ignore this error as long as it still generates the net connections in the PCB/layout file.

Comment: I have found that even if another port with the same name exists at the next level up, it may be necessary to disconnect and reconnect them.